# PDF.js: how to display page ranges?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf.js

I'm using [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) in a web application for searching over a collection of PDF files. All goes fine? using the 'default' viewer.html viewer for displaying the PDF files, and using the `#page=` query parameter to jump to the relevant page. Yet, printing takes a miserable amount of time ("Preparing document for printing…"), which degrades the user experience.

What would be really interesting is the possibility to only show the pages of the PDF files containing the actual result(s).

Is there a way to display only a selected page range of a PDF file with PDF.js? Ideally, since those search results are generated dynamically, it would be great if those ranges could be passed as URL parameters (analogous to the `#page` parameter in the URL query string, e.g.:

- `#pages=1-10`
- `#from=1&to=10`

I've searched but haven't found any examples so far. Is this possible at all?

Comment: You can modify the PDF.js demo viewer to handle such query arguments.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I'm not confident with the advanced JS techniques used in PDF.js; do you perhaps know any pointers to similar attempts that could set me on track?

Comment: Just reading the code and invest in learning the project will be first right step